# How to easily insert values to tables which have different amount of attributes?

Tags: c#, database, forms

I am making a 3-layered architecture database application with C# Windows Form application and an Excel file. Problem is, I have three tables and they have different amount of attributes. I want to user chooses which table he/she want to insert and update.

The basic solution is making three different forms to add values to each table, because **for different amount of inputs I need different amount of textboxes.** But it's too troublesome and amateurish, I think.

Can you give me some advise to do this easily?

Comment: use `user control` then

Comment: @Rahul Thank you my friend! I just learned it and I think it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Something that you could try is using a DataGridView.

A drop-down could be used to determine what table the user would like to modify. Based on this input, query your database and bind the results with the DataGridView.

A reference you could start with "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/data-entry-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control"

Answer (score -1):

Simpler method will be a big table with all the fields. Allow null on the ones you will allow user to skip.
OR

Create a table with bare minimum fields a user must enter. Create other tables and connect them using a foreign key constraint. On the front end, allow the users to leave fields empty. You should be done.